# PowerShell in Variable in quotation marks

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, I would like to run the following command:

```
$User = Read-Host -Prompt "User"
$PW1 = Read-Host -Prompt "Password1"
$PW2 = Read-Host -Prompt "Password2"

'.\imapsync.exe --host1 192.168.0.69 --user1 $User@Example.com --password1 $PW1  ^
               --host2  172.20.100.96 --user2 $User@Example.lokal --password2 $PW2 ^
               --automap --exclude "&ANY-ffentlicher Ordner" --exclude "Freigegebene Postfächer"' | out-file C:\Users\User\Downloads\Test\Test_$User.bat
```

in the batch file the variables are not resolved but only "$ User" and not the user specified at the beginning

Comment: A single-quoted string does not have variable substitution enabled. Use double quotes instead; the double quotes inside the string can be escaped with the backtick (`\`"`).

Comment: [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules).